# Add vertices to face after using bisect

Tags: subdivision-surface, bisect

I made a cut through an object using the "bisect" tool. In this case I wanted to cut through the center "dome" part of the flower shown below. This pretty much worked as expected, but it left me with one large face along the plane of the bisect. I would like to subdivide this large face adding many more vertices because I will need to sculpt on it later.

I tried selecting the face in edit mode, right clicking, and selecting "subdivide" but this adds no vertices on the large face.

How do I subdivide this large face created from the bisect?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the geometry you've created and the geometry you are looking for, here are two approaches that work.

1. repeated inset

   If you can select the edge loop around the face, you can use the <kbd>I</kbd> key to inset it several times creating a looping pattern.  When you have enough loops, do one more, and with the vertices still selected type <kbd>M</kbd> and select *at center*.

   Here is a circle, filled using the inset technique:

   [image: Circle filled using insets]
2. grid fill

   You can remove the face, select the resulting edge loop and use *Face* → *Grid Fill* from the menu to create a repeating grid.

   Here is a circle filled using a grid fill:

   [image: Circle filled using grid fill]

If you can't select the edge loop, you can accomplish the same thing by selecting all of the vertices around the edge using other selection tools.

Each technique has its own strengths and weaknesses, mostly when it comes to topology.  The inset technique allows you to easily select edge rings while the grid fill doesn't.